# Hyperparameter filtering for scalar output tensorboard

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I am using tensorboard along with pytorch in order to monitor the training metrics of my model: when it comes to hyperparameter optimization, I end up having quite a few scalar events (training loss) with various parameter combinations. Is it possible to filter some of these graphs out based on the value of the hyperparameter? It seems like the `hparam` feature only lets you record the final metric: ideally I don't want either to use the `comment` parameter of `SummaryWriter`  to do so and filter it with a regex as it offers a limited number of characters.